# Dual Gateway Setup in Mikrotik

Tags: routing, gateway, mikrotik, ip-routing

##### I'm new to Mikrotik environment, and I need some help for the following scenario:

- I have an ADSL router (main internet connection) with IP range of `192.168.1.0/24`, connected to **Ethernet 1** of my Mikrotik router (WAN Port)
- I have another ADSL router (VPN connection to connect to main branch)  with IP range of `172.200.1.0/24`, connected to **Ethernet 2** of my Mikrotik router
- I have WiFi enabled Mikrotik as Ap bridge with IP range of `192.168.88.0/24` (everyone connect to this router using WiFi and physical connection)

##### What I want to do is as follows:

- When people want to access the Internet, the Mikrotik router should route packets automatically to **Ethernet 1** interface (first ADSL).
- If people want to go to certain destinations (e.g. `221.35.12.x`) their packet has to be routed to **Ethernet 2**, which is the Second ADSL to connect to main branch.

##### Additional information

The gateway for first ADSL is `192.168.1.1`, and for second one is `172.200.1.17`.

So far, I have managed to access the gateway of the second ADSL, but when I ping the actual destination address of `221.35.12.x`, it returns `unreachable` and when I `tracert` that address, it shows the packet goes to `192.168.88.1` and from there drops.

Can anyone help for the above scenario with a complete solution?

Comment: Please show your routes and firewall rules, `/ip route print` and `/ip firewall xxx print` where `xxx` is `filter`, `mangle`,`nat`, `raw`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, since I haven't manage to get in to the solution I reset all the setting. can you please guide me through for above scenario?

Comment: anyone else can help  me on above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preliminary setup: You will need to set up the two WAN connections.  Assume `IFC1` to be the first WAN port (e.g. `ether1`) interface and `IFC2` to be the second WAN port (e.g. `ether5`).

```
/interface list member add interface=IFC1 list=WAN
/interface list member add interface=IFC2 list=WAN
/ip dhcp-client add interface=IFC1 default-route-distance=1
/ip dhcp-client add interface=IFC2 default-route-distance=1
```

Some of this may already be configured.  If using a different type of WAN connection such as PPPoE then adjust accordingly.

When the DHCP client connects, routes should be added, below is an example.

```
[admin@mikrotik] > /ip route print
Flags: X - disabled, A - active, D - dynamic,
C - connect, S - static, r - rip, b - bgp, o - ospf, m - mme,
B - blackhole, U - unreachable, P - prohibit
 #      DST-ADDRESS        PREF-SRC        GATEWAY            DISTANCE
 0 ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          yyy.yy.yyy.1              1
 1 ADS  0.0.0.0/0                          xxx.xxx.xxx.1             1
 2 ADC  xxx.xxx.xxx.0/22   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IFC2                      0
...
```

If you don't see two `0.0.0.0/0` routes with the correct gateways, you can create them as static routes (`/ip route add ...`).  This is basic Mikrotik stuff beyond the scope of this answer.

Differentiating between the two WAN connections will be done using policy routing.  On each default WAN route set a routing mark.

```
/ip route set 0 routing-mark=unid2rm
/ip route set 1 routing-mark=unid3rm
```

The values `unid2rm` and `unid3rm` are arbitrary text strings.  This means the Mikrotik will send packets marked with a given routing mark through the given gateway IP.

Second, configure the firewall.  Look at the `FORWARD` chain.  The goal here is to exclude marked connections for the secondary (non-default) WAN from going through fasttrack.

```
/ip firewall filter add 8 chain=forward action=fasttrack-connection connection-state=established,related connection-mark=!unid2cm
/ip firewall filter add 9 chain=forward action=accept connection-state=established,related
```

Change the numbers 8 and 9 so that the rules are positioned at the start of your `FORWARD` chain.

Now in the `PREROUTING` chain, mark the **incoming** connections.  If you're only steering outbound connections, you can skip this.

```
/ip firewall mangle add 3 chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=unid2cm passthrough=no connection-mark=no-mark in-interface=IFC1
/ip firewall mangle add 4 chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=unid3cm passthrough=no connection-mark=no-mark in-interface=IFC2
```

The next step involves the `MANGLE` table and is where the magic happens for you.  Here you mark a connection based on the criteria you set.

```
/ip firewall mangle add 5 chain=prerouting action=mark-connection new-connection-mark=unid2cm passthrough=yes dst-address=221.35.12.5 connection-mark=no-mark in-interface-list=LAN
```

This is saying "when there is a connection to `221.35.12.5` which is not already marked, mark it with connection mark `unid2cm`".  You can set it based on source IP, MAC, etc. and add as many of these as needed.  Then the companion is:

```
/ip firewall mangle add 6 chain=prerouting action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=unid2rm passthrough=no connection-mark=unid2cm in-interface-list=LAN
/ip firewall mangle add 7 chain=output action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=unid2rm passthrough=no connection-mark=unid2cm
/ip firewall mangle add 8 chain=prerouting action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=unid3rm passthrough=no connection-mark=unid3cm in-interface-list=LAN
/ip firewall mangle add 9 chain=output action=mark-routing new-routing-mark=unid3rm passthrough=no connection-mark=unid3cm
```

Note the difference between `unid2rm` and `unid2cm`.  These rules take packets from a marked *connection* and give them a routing mark.  The routing mark is then used in Mikrotik's route table as mentioned earlier.

Every setup is a bit different, so you might need to play around to make it work for you.

---

Added: Mikrotik usually sets up NAT automatically on the `WAN` interface list.  The very first step at the top of the answer ensures that both interfaces are in the list.

```
[admin@mikrotik] > /ip firewall nat print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic
 0    ;;; defconf: masquerade
      chain=srcnat action=masquerade out-interface-list=WAN log=no
      log-prefix=""
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for great walkthrough. how about Nat Setup?  Do I need to set it up as well? if yes for which WAN connection?

Comment: Putting the interfaces in the `WAN` list (the first two commands in the answer) means both are NATted in the default Mikrotik setup. Added to end of answer.